# Ploting Freeman chain code of an object - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Based on previous posts (for example, https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/725807-freeman-chain-code-object-plot , [Extract Freeman chain code of an object - Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752127/extract-freeman-chain-code-of-an-object-matlab)) I update this code to extract boundaries from an image, convert them to chain code and plot the chain code. As Matlab flip the axis so how can I match the chain code drawing to match the original image?

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
 
sz = 25;
Image = rgb2gray(imread('https://upload-icon.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/icons/png/1606078271536061993-512.png'));
 
binaryImage = imbinarize(Image);
binaryImage = imfill(binaryImage,'holes');
binaryImage = bwareaopen(binaryImage, 100);
binaryImage = padarray(binaryImage,60,60,'both')
binaryImage = imcomplement(binaryImage);
 
imshow(binaryImage);
axis on;
hold on; 
 
boundaries = bwboundaries(binaryImage);
 
%%%%%%%% Extract chain code
for k = 1 : length(boundaries)
    % Get the k'th boundary.
    thisBoundary = boundaries{k};
    % Get the x and y coordinates.
    x = thisBoundary(:, 2);
    y = thisBoundary(:, 1);
    % Plot this boundary over the original image.
    hold on;
    plot(x, y, 'g-', 'LineWidth', 2);
    scatter(x(1,1), y(1,1),sz, 'filled') % Mark starting point
    % Create the chain code.
    for p = 2 : length(y)
        % See where the current point is relative to the prior point.
        if x(p) < x(p-1) && y(p) < y(p-1)
            % Moved to the upper left
            thisChainCode(p) = 1;
        elseif x(p) == x(p-1) && y(p) < y(p-1)
            % Moved straight up
            thisChainCode(p) = 2;
        elseif x(p) > x(p-1) && y(p) < y(p-1)
            % Moved to the upper right
            thisChainCode(p) = 3;
        elseif x(p) > x(p-1) && y(p) == y(p-1)
            % Moved right
            thisChainCode(p) = 4;
        elseif x(p) > x(p-1) && y(p) > y(p-1)
            % Moved right and down.
            thisChainCode(p) = 5;
        elseif x(p) == x(p-1) && y(p) > y(p-1)
            % Moved down
            thisChainCode(p) = 6;
        elseif x(p) <= x(p-1) && y(p) > y(p-1)
            % Moved down and left
            thisChainCode(p) = 7;
        elseif x(p) <= x(p-1) && y(p) == y(p-1)
            % Moved left
            thisChainCode(p) = 8;
        end
    end
    % Save the chain code that we built up for this boundary
    % into the cell array that will contain all chain codes.
    chainCodes{k} = thisChainCode
end
 
%%%%%%%% Plot chain code
%celldisp(chainCodes);
cc=num2str(cell2mat(chainCodes));
cc(cc == ' ') = []
c = 'b';
x = zeros(strlength(cc)+1,1); %Consider storing values and pre-allocating to save time
y = zeros(strlength(cc)+1,1); 
x(1) = 100;
y(1) = 50;
 
figure %Creates a blank figure object
for i = 1 : strlength(cc)
    switch str2double(cc(i)) %Switches are faster than if/elseif with this many options
        case {0 8} %Assumes 0 and 8 are the same case
            x(i+1) = x(i)+1;
            y(i+1) = y(i);
        case 1
            x(i+1) = x(i)+1;
            y(i+1) = y(i)+1;
        case 2
            x(i+1) = x(i);
            y(i+1) = y(i)+1;
        case 3
            x(i+1) = x(i)-1;
            y(i+1) = y(i)+1;
        case 4
            x(i+1) = x(i)-1;
            y(i+1) = y(i);
        case 5
            x(i+1) = x(i)-1;
            y(i+1) = y(i)-1;
        case 6
            x(i+1) = x(i);
            y(i+1) = y(i)-1;
        case 7
            x(i+1) = x(i)+1;
            y(i+1) = y(i)-1;
        otherwise
            error('Invalid')
    end
end
%One plot for efficiency
scatter(x,y,sz,c,'filled')
%Sets plot area and aspect ratio to display image properly
axis tight
daspect([1 1 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to substitute the following at the end:

```
scatter(-x+max(x),-y+max(y),sz,c,'filled');
axis ij;
axis tight;
daspect([1 1 1]);
```

Figure(1):
[image: First MATLAB figure]

Figure(2):
[image: Second MATLAB figure]

The figure axes are now in the correct orientation. If the pixel indices must also match, just translate the plot by a fixed offset.